# wrong result from linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I write this query but the result from it is wrong

```
var query = from item in db.Advances
            where CurrentConfiguration.currentLanguage == GeneralDefinitions.arabicSymbol 
                  ? item.eUser.name.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
                  : item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
            && !item.isPaid 
            && item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month 
            && item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year
            && item.advanceTypeId == (int)enumAdvanceType.AtOnce
            select item;
```

The wrong is in

```
item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month 
&& item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year
```

It is always `true` although `item.expectedPaymentMonth != dExpectedPayment.Month` 
Is there any syntax error or something wrong in this query ?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you replaced the `&&` with separate `where` clauses?

Comment: @Enigmativity it is working perfect you can edit it and put it as answer to mark it as a right answer Thanks

Comment: all answers are solving the problem thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from item in db.Advances
    where (CurrentConfiguration.currentLanguage
            == GeneralDefinitions.arabicSymbol
            ? item.eUser.name
            : item.eUser.englishName).ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
    where !item.isPaid
    where item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month
    where item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year
    where item.advanceTypeId == (int)enumAdvanceType.AtOnce
    select item;
```

I suspect that the ternary operator is causing you grief.

Answer (score 2):

You must group `boolean`s because of `?:` expression! See:

```
var query = from item in db.Advances
            where 
            (
                CurrentConfiguration.currentLanguage == GeneralDefinitions.arabicSymbol 
                ? item.eUser.name.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
                : item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
            )
            && !item.isPaid 
            && item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month 
            && item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year
            && item.advanceTypeId == (int)enumAdvanceType.AtOnce
            select item;
```

If you don't use `()`, all expressions after `item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)` will be `AND` with `item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)` and finally returns a single result!
**ALSO** you can use separate where clauses:

```
var query = from item in db.Advances
            where 
                CurrentConfiguration.currentLanguage == GeneralDefinitions.arabicSymbol 
                ? item.eUser.name.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
                : item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey)
            where !item.isPaid 
                && item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month 
                && item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year
                && item.advanceTypeId == (int)enumAdvanceType.AtOnce
            select item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because the ? operator is not between () and you are testing arabicSymbol ?

try: (extra lines added for clarity)

```
where

(

CurrentConfiguration.currentLanguage == GeneralDefinitions.arabicSymbol ? item.eUser.name.ToLower  ().Contains(strSearchKey) : item.eUser.englishName.ToLower().Contains(strSearchKey) 

)
                    && !item.isPaid && item.expectedPaymentMonth == dExpectedPayment.Month && item.expectedPaymentYear == dExpectedPayment.Year 
                    && item.advanceTypeId == (int)enumAdvanceType.AtOnce 
                    select item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers above are correct as they relate to operator prescedence (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

The && is evaluated before the ?:.  Therefore you're effectively seeing all the &&'s being applied the the else portion of the ?: expression.